# GCP Pub/Sub Push Subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working with GCP Pub/Sub within a Cloud Run service, as per the documentation I am required to use a [push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#retrieve-code:%7E:text=for%20your%20project.-,Create%20a%20Pub/Sub%20subscription%20with%20the%20service%20account%3A,-gcloud%20pubsub%20subscriptions).

The push endpoint is configured and is working, I was testing the error case on the push endpoint to make sure that Pub/Sub would not retry delivery in an infinite loop.

After following the documentation I have been unable to get the Dead Letter Queues working with the push subscription.

How can I configure a fixed amount of retries with a push subscription? Code below.

````
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

async function pubsubInit() {
  await pubSubClient.createTopic(config.asyncTasks.topic);
  await pubSubClient.createTopic(config.asyncTasks.deadletter);
  await pubSubClient.createSubscription(config.asyncTasks.topic, config.asyncTasks.sub, {
    deadLetterPolicy: {
      deadLetterTopic: config.asyncTasks.deadletter,
      maxDeliveryAttempts: 5,
    },
    pushEndpoint: config.asyncTasks.endpoint,
  });

  await pubSubClient.createSubscription(config.asyncTasks.deadletter, config.asyncTasks.deadletterSub, {
    pushEndpoint: config.asyncTasks.deadEndpoint,
  });
}```
````

Comment: Are you sure that your messages are nack? And that the Push Subscription service account has the permission to publish in the new topic?

Comment: I am intentionally returning a 500 status code to simulate a bad response from the subscriber. So I know that the subscriber is getting the message and returning a back ack.

Comment: So now, what about the subscription service account permission to publish a message in the topic?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the service subscribing to the topic also has the proper permissions to publish to that queue.

Comment: You can use this [document](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#set_a_on_a_new_subscription) to set a dead-letter topic on subscription and use `setMaxDeliveryAttempts` to set number of retries. Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT when I configure a dead-letter queue on the push subscription the 'maxDeliveryAttempts' property is not respected.

Comment: Are you able to include `maxDeliveryAttempts` from the console? Did you try this [code](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#set_a_on_a_new_subscription) to set `maxDeliveryAttempts`? If your subscriber repeatedly didn't ack this message, then with `max_delivery_attempts` set to 5, It would take approximately `5 * ack_deadline_seconds` for the message to end up in the dead letter topic (and to be acked by Cloud Pub/Sub so that it is not delivered to your subscriber again).